# Button Line Break in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0, arcgis

Working on the XAML file and C# at the back end. 
I have totally 4 buttons.

By clicking 1st, other three will be Visible and by clicking same 1st button the three will hide.

Though they are working fine, I want them to aligned vertical and not horizontal by breaking the line.

Also I need to add images before each buttons. Something like [this](http://tinypic.com/r/29maufo/5).

Please suggest. Thank you.

[Followed](http://goo.gl/MovCO8) this answer, but I understand its for the text and not for buttons.

Here's by code for the buttons:

```
<Button Content ="Buttons" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="15,15,15,15"></Button>

<Button Content="Topo Map" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="Topo_OnClick"
Name="But2" Margin="15,15,15,15"/>

<Button Content="Street Map" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="Street_OnClick"
Name="But3" Margin="15,15,15,15"/>

<Button Content="Imagery Map" Visibility="Collapsed"Click="Imagery_OnClick"
Name="But4" Margin="15,15,15,15"/>
```

Comment: Not clear about exactly what do you want to achieve. If you want buttons in a column you can use Stack with "Vertical Orientation". And with-in each row if you want an image along with button, again use stack with horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap your buttons in a content container, like a stackpanel or grid.  Keep in mind a stack panel will size to fit it's contents where a grid can size to fit available space.  I would use a stackpanel to hold the buttons and a grid to hold your button content:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="15">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image />
                <TextBlock Text="Buttons" />
            </Grid>
        </Button>

        ...

    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the WrapPanel of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SilverlightToolkit-All/).